# Error getting text from html table using beutifulsoup and mechanize

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to get text from an html code inside a table tag,but I'm not getting all of the text.Instead I get some partial  text and the rest is ignored

Here is my output and code:

output

```
Public Sector Organization (Recruitment Test)
Test held on: Saturday, 3rd & Sunday 4th, December 2016
>>>
```

code

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from PIL import Image
import os


Roll=60170001          

url = "http://nts.org.pk/Test&Products/Results/012017/PubSecOrg_24122016_Result/Search.php"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False) # ignore robots
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)                                                            
rollnumber=str(Roll)
captcha=11111
cap=str(captcha)                        
br["RollNo"]=rollnumber
br["captcha"]=cap
res = br.submit()
content = res.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
rolln=soup('table')[2]
rolln=rolln.text.encode('utf-8')
print rolln
```

Comment: What is the requested output?

Comment: In principle my output should be the whole text inside table[2],,which is somewhat like this..   Public Sector Organization (Recruitment Test)
Test held on: Saturday, 3rd & Sunday 4th, December 2016 (Result)
Upload Date :  Wednesday, 23rd November 2016  Search Result for the keyword   60170001                             
Roll No
Name
Father Name
CNIC
Post
NTS Marks
60170001 
MUMTAZ ALI                               
RAHMAN WALI  
16101-1938424-7  
    Lecturer (BPS-17) (Electronics)   
    67  Current Date / Time: Wednesday 22nd, February 2017 , 09:30:48 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach seems to do what you want.

```
>>> content = open(r"C:\scratch\___National Testing Service___.html").read()
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
>>> tables = soup.findAll('table')
>>> len(tables)
8
>>> tables[2].text
'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nPublic Sector Organization (Recruitment Test)\nTest held on: Saturday, 3rd & Sunday 4th, December 2016\n\n                            \n                            (Result)\n\n\n\n\n\n                                Search Result for the keyword   "\n                                60170001                             \n"\n\n\n\nRoll No\nName\nFather Name\nCNIC\n\nPost\n\n\nKDPH\n\n\nNTS Marks\n\n\n\n60170001\nSARA ISLAM                               \nNAZAR UL ISLAM  \n17301-2406027-4  \n\n    Assistant Manager(Electronics Engineering)   \n\n\n      \n\n\n    63   \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nCurrent Date / Time: Tuesday 21st, February 2017 , 11:49:59 PM                           \n\n\n\n\n\xa0\n\n'
```

Assuming that `mechanize` gives you the file in the same format that I was able to obtain simply by opening the page in the Chrome browser and saving it you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Finally it worked perfectly. just installed lxml.

Comment: You're welcome. I couldn't be sure what the problem might be.